# Disable republish in Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

How to disable re-publish of the same version of the artifact in the Jfrog Artifactory?
For example Docker repository - my-docker-releases: Image myapp:1.0.0 is published in the repository. It should not be possible for anyone to publish another image with the same tag myapp:1.0.0 in the same repository.
How to achieve this feature by repository settings of Artifactory?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in their documentation:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Managing+Permissions

> **Preventing Overwriting Deployments**
>
> You can prevent a user or group from overwriting a deployed release or unique snapshot by not granting the Delete permission. Non-unique snapshots can always be overwritten (provided the Deploy permission is granted).